# SQL Server Group BY Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, group-by

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE #weeks(
  ProposalLineWeekID INT, 
  StartWeek DATETIME, 
  EndWeek DATETIME, 
  Selected BIT, 
  WeekNumber INT
)
```

How do I get all the `ProposalLineWeekID` values that have duplicate `WeekNumber` entries? 
For instance

```
ProposalLineWeekID, WeekNumber 
------------------------------
2                   22
3                   6
4                   22
```

I'd like to get ProposalLineWeekID 2 and 4 with the accompanying WeekNumber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProposalLineWeekID, WeekNumber
FROM #Weeks
WHERE WeekNumber IN
( 
    SELECT WeekNumber
    FROM #weeks
    GROUP BY WeekNumber
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

The subquery finds all the duplicated week numbers and the outer query fetches the corresponding rows.

Comment: +1, this will work as well.  Not sure which of my or your solution would perform better in practice though.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding correctly, I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w1.ProposalLineWeekID, w1.WeekNumber
FROM weeks w1
INNER JOIN weeks w2 ON w2.WeekNumber = w1.WeekNumber 
  AND w2.ProposalLineWeekID <> w1.ProposalLineWeekID
```

Comment: +1 but you might want to add WeekNumber (what the OP asked for) and `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause in the case a given weeknumber is duplicated more than twice

Comment: @Conrad - good points, I had the distinct in there originally then thought twice about it and removed it.  Should have stuck with my first instinct there :)